# How to create an a element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a DIV using `JavaScript` and I want to make it an `<a href>` element.

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
element.className = 'element';
element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So change it to `a` and set the `element.href`...

Comment: I think you want to add an onclick event for the div.

document.getElementByClassName("element").addEventListener("click", yourFunction);

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` element does not have the `href` attribute, you need to use an `<a>`. 
If you still want to use a `<div>` which behaves like an `<a>` you can attach to it a **click event** with javascript that will trigger a location change (o whatever you want to do):

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );

element.className = 'element';
element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';

element.addEventListener('click', function(){    
  window.location = 'someUrl.html';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that you can transform a page that has a DIV created with JavaScript such that the element is replaced by an anchor with an HREF attribute, as follows:

```
function doit() {

var mydiv = document.getElementById( 'mydiv' );
document.getElementById('bod').removeChild( mydiv );
var element = document.createElement('a');
var node = document.createTextNode('php.net');
element.href="http://www.php.net";
element.appendChild(node);
document.getElementById('bod').appendChild( element );
}

function query() {
var ans = confirm("replace div with anchor?");
  if ( ans == true ){
    doit();
  }
}

var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
element.id = 'mydiv';
element.innerText = 'please click here';
element.className = 'element';
element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
element.style.width='220px';
element.style.height='150px';
element.onclick = query;
document.getElementById('bod').appendChild(element);
```

If one should wonder why anyone would write code like this, well, I did myself some years back to present the user with a dynamic page and it was a cool effect.

This solution runs with Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I tested the script on my local webserver.

Answer (score -1):

it's a div.. not an an anchor element.. so it doesnt make much sense to change it.  if you want it act like a hyperlink using javascript you can do this

```
element.onclick = function(){
    document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```